# "Unable to write in the cache directory" with Docker and Nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've set up docker with nginx and php:fpm and I'm getting the:

`"Unable to write in the cache directory" Could not create cache directory`

or

`"/usr/share/nginx/html/app/cache/dev/annotations".`

errors no matter what I try. I know this is a common error but being new to Nginx and not great on Linux and I can't seem to figure out what users I need to create and what permissions I need to create and where?

I've tried adding the below into my nginx:latest dockerfile but no luck. Any ideas?

`RUN adduser www-data www-data
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/app/cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/app/logs
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/app/cache/*
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/app/logs/*`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

ADD . /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN adduser www-data www-data
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/app/cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/app/logs
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/app/cache/*
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/app/logs/*

ADD /docker_setup/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD /docker_setup/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

ENV TERM xterm

EXPOSE 80
```

Docker compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        # image: nginx:latest
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
        links:
            - php
        volumes_from:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    php:
        image: php:fpm
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Are you doing volume mounts in your docker run/docker-compose commands?

Comment: @IanEllis - I've updated my question with the dockerfile and compose files. thanks

Comment: The user in docker needs to have permissions for the files/directories in host. Usually create the user in docker with same uid/gid as user on docker host.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do this, or what I need to run? @IanEllis

Comment: Either get the user id/group id of the volumes you want to mount with "ls -n" then create the nginx user in your Dockerfile with adduser -u / -g options OR (e.g. if nginx user already created in FROM image) add nginx user to your host machine and make sure the assets being volume mounted are owned by nginx.

Comment: @IanEllis - running ls -n on the cache folder results in "total 0".. shouldn't there be permissions/group info with that? 'whoami' results in root from docker

Comment: "ls -nd . ./logs/nginx" will show uid/gid on the docker host. Because the directory you did ls against was empty it didn't return anything, hence need for -d argument.